# Unenforced relationship for look up columns on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am facing this situation where deleting an item from the target list deletes the data on the source list.

Context:
I have a source list, Register which have a look up column pointing to a target list, Courses.

However when I delete the item on Courses, any past data in Register for that lookup column with the deleted item will also be deleted.

No relationship behavior was selected during the creation of the lookup column.

Is this as intended?

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Hello, @MangeshGhotage, this is plain sharepoint UI no code was used.

Answer (score 0):

While you are creating the lookup, check the Enforce relationship behavior option.

**Edit:**
For maintaining the lookup I would suggest creating an event receiver that will check on deleting if the child list has any item connected to it and prevent the deletion process.

```
        public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            // your code to check if child list has items.
            if(hasItems)
            {
                 properties.ErrorMessage = "Object is being used in another list";
                 properties.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello Yasseen, if i were to enforce relationship, I would not be able to delete the item at the target list and keeping the item at source list intact.

Comment: Hello Yaseen, how do i delete something from the parent list and retaining the item in the child list?